# Accessing files on Pi over HTTPS

Tags: usb, security

I've installed [Baracuda](http://barracudadrive.com/) drive on my Raspberry Pi in order to access files located on an attached USB drive from a browser. This works well in my local network and now I want to open a port on my router to access the files via the internet. I want to use an HTTPS connection for obvious reasons, but this is not supported by default.

Baracuda drive has some tunneling software as desribed [here](http://barracudadrive.com/MxTunnel.lsp), but it doesn't seem to work on a Pi's architecture. I get a:

> ./MxTunnel: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

when I try to run it.

So to get HTTPS working, I want to install software called [Stunnel](http://www.stunnel.org). **Is this a good way to get my HTTPS connection up and running or are there easier/better alternatives?**

Comment: You do realize that MxTunnel is a client, right? (which means that you should run it on the computer you're using to access your files)

Comment: I thought it was for the server

Comment: Nyope. You thought wrong.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot use MxTunnel on the pi since I checked MxTunnel out and they provide a pre-compiled binary (which I'm sure is for x86 or x64, not ARM).

Probably the most convenient option (in my opinion) would be SFTP which is FTP with an S on it (which means secure). It's quite easy to set up using `vsftpd` and a few port forwards. Using Filezilla to access your files surely won't hurt except for the fact that you need that software to access your home files.

Comment: I don't want to install any software to access the files, so that's why I don't want to use sftp.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile Stunnel from source; it looks like it is only distributed precompiled for android or x86-64, which is not uncommon. Fortunately there is a `.tar.gz` package on their [downloads page](https://www.stunnel.org/downloads.html).

Open that up:

```
tar -xzf stunnel-5.30.tar.gz
```

Then:

```
cd stunnel-5.30
./configure --help
```

This will show you some options but they are probably not very interesting.  The only one you need to use is `--with-gnu-ld` and even that is usually irrelevant.

You will need some stuff installed first; on Raspbian at least:

```
apt-get install gcc
apt-get install make
apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Then from within the unpacked directory try:

```
./configure --with-gnu-ld
make
make test
```

The last one may not happen, try `make check` if it doesn't.  If neither one works don't worry about it.

Finally:

```
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

I'm not sure that `sudo make` works (it really shouldn't...but that's tangential).  You may need to `su root` instead to run `make install`.

Comment: So I was able to install Stunnel, but I realized now that I can just access baracuda directly via https. I have no idea why I assumed they don't support it. I guess that whole page on MXTunnel confused me.